# Got undefined variable when using it in the component but it is defined in the template

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**Got undefined variable when using it in the component but it is defined in the template**

Im noobie :p

when i try to get this.authService.queue_start in console i get undefined

```js
public queue_start: string;
constructor(private http: Http, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if(token){
        this.http.get('api/v1/user?token='+ token)
          .subscribe(
              response => {
                  this.authService.dataa = response;
                  this.authService.queue_start = this.authService.dataa.json().queue_start;
                  },
              error => console.log(error),
          );
    }



if(this.authService.queue_start == "1"){
     console.log(this.authService.queue_start,"queue_start = 1");
   }else {
  console.log(this.authService.queue_start);
   }
}
```

Comment: would you mind specifying which variable is undefined

Comment: this.authService.queue_start

Comment: after this line `this.authService.dataa = response;`, try `console.log(this.authService.dataa.json());` to see what the response looks like

Comment: I get {id: 27, username: "hASVAN", email: "dh@gmail.com", Points: "999", queue_start: "1"}

Comment: Ah I see, the problem is because `http.get` returns an observable, therefore your code run in async. I've put an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `http.get` return an observable, therefore your code will run in async.. These line here:

```
if(this.authService.queue_start == "1"){
   console.log(this.authService.queue_start,"queue_start = 1");
}else {
   console.log(this.authService.queue_start);
}
```

will get executed before `this.http.get('api/v1/user?token='+ token)` gives the result.

In order to solve this, you have to made `this.http.get('api/v1/user?token='+ token)` into a new method which return a promise.

```
getData(token): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('api/v1/user?token='+ token)
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    resolve(response.json().queue_start);
                },
                error => console.log(error));
    });
}
```

To call this async method in the `constructor` would be like this:

```
if(token){
    this.getData(token).then(queueStart => console.log(queueStart));
}
```

Now you should be able to see that `queueStart` would have the result that you want.

This is what your class now looks like:

```
public queue_start: string;

constructor(private http: Http, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(token){
        this.getData(token).then(queueStart => console.log(queueStart));
    }
}

getData(token): Promise<any> {
    //....
}
```

**---------------UPDATE------------------**

To use the result you get, you would use it like this:

```
if(token){
    this.getData(token).then(queueStart => {
        this.authService.queue_start = queueStart;
        if(this.authService.queue_start == "1"){
            console.log(this.authService.queue_start,"queue_start = 1");
        }else {
            console.log(this.authService.queue_start);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry im new in angular where do i need to add  getData: Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {this.http.get('api/v1/user?token='+ token)
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            resolve(response.json().queue_start);
        },
        error => console.log(error));
});

Comment: put it in the class as its method, let me update the answer @hasvan

Comment: thx man but when  i add    this.getData(token).subscribe(queueStart => console.log(queueStart)); I get this error ERROR in /var/www/battle/src/app/app.component.ts (31,33): Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.

Comment: @hasvan yep that's also my typo, my bad, change `subscribe` to `then`

Comment: its working were do i need to add please this.authService.dataa = response;
                  this.router.navigateByUrl('play');
                  this.authService.isLoggedIn = true;
                  console.log(this.authService.dataa.json().id);
                  this.authService.avatar = this.authService.dataa.json().avatar;
                  this.authService.queue_start = this.authService.dataa.json().queue_start;
                  this.authService.Points = this.authService.dataa.json().Points;
                  this.authService.username = this.authService.dataa.json().username;

Comment: @hasvan I assume those are statements which need to be called after you get your response. Therefore put those inside the `then`, just like the `console.log(queueStart)`.. But because you have multiple statements, don't forget the `{ }` mark... So it would be like this `then(queueStart => { /*your multiple statement goes here*/ });`

Comment: can you please show me how to add getData to the if and show me how to make this as the answer and thx you if(this.authService.queue_start == "1"){
   console.log(this.authService.queue_start,"queue_start = 1");
}else {
   console.log(this.authService.queue_start);
}

Comment: thx for your time man i hope you get all the happiness you deserve